My hand [swole]/[has swollen] up where the bee stung me
John and Sarah went hiking in the forest, and a bee stung John. At first, he didn't notice anything, but the next day his hand swole up where the bee had stung him.
Scenario #1:
He and Sarah met in person the next day. He showed her his hand and said: "Look, my hand [swole]/[has swollen] up where the bee stung me."
Scenario #2:
Sarah called him and asked him: "How's your hand?". He replied: "It has swollen up where the bee stung me."
Question:
In scenario #1, I think either option is correct because Sarah can see the swollen hand. Thus, the present perfect "has swollen up" doesn't add anything to the meaning. In scenario #2, I believe the present perfect "has swollen up" is the only correct choice because she can't see anything on the phone, and John needs to convey that his hand is now swollen, which is the function of the present perfect.
Do you agree? Thank you.

"His hand swelled up". Swole as the past tense of swell is archaic or dialect.

principal parts of swell [up]; swell swelled, swollen

This question is similar to: verb tense: Present Perfect vs Simple Past. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

@Lambie I personally think the "swole" is different enough to keep this?

@Kaia  Why bother with it when an OP doesn't even know the right principal parts? Kate has explained it. That's enough.
